# Divisors of $2^kp$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. What is the necessary and sufficient condition (in terms of $p$ and $k$) such that we can partition the divisors of $2^kp$ into two set with equal sum.

Comment: Have you tried just considering the set of divisors $1,2,2^2,...,2^k\cup p,2p,(2^2)p,...,(2^k)p$ . Then you want each set to add up to $\frac{p+1}{2}(2^{k+1}-1)$ and going from there?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N=2^kp$. The divisors of $N$ are $1,2,4,\dots, 2^k$ and $p,2p,4p,\dots, 2^kp$. Their sum simplifies to $(2^{k+1}-1)(p+1)$.

If we divide the divisors of $N$ into two sets, then $N$ will be in one of the sets. The sum of the *rest* of the divisors is $(2^{k+1}-1)(p+1)-2^kp$. This simplifies to 
$$N +(2^{k+1}-1-p).$$
If the term $2^{k+1}-1-p$ is *negative*, then the divisors less than $N$ add up to less than $N$, so we cannot do the required splitting.

If $2^{k+1}-1-p$ is $\ge 0$, then we *can* do the splitting. In the case $2^{k+1}-1-p=0$, the number $N$ is a  **perfect number**. The splitting consists of $N$ as the only member of one of the sets, and all the  rest of the divisor of $N$ in the other set.

Now we verify that we can do the splitting also in the case $2^{k+1}-1-p\gt 0$. 
If we put just $N$ into set $A$, and the rest of the divisors into set  $B$, then set $A$ has sum $N$ and set $B$ has sum $N +(2^{k+1}-1-p)$. So we must "transfer" from $B$ to $A$ a collection of numbers with sum $\frac{2^{k+1}-1-p}{2}$.

This is easy to do. For the number $\frac{2^{k+1}-1-p}{2}$ is less than $2^{k+1}-1$. And any number $\le 2^{k+1}-1$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct powers of $2$ each $\le 2^k$. These powers of $2$ are among the divisors of $N$, so by shifting suitable divisors of $N$ from $B$ to $A$ we get the desired splitting.

There is even a mechanical method of doing it: just write down the binary representation of $\frac{2^{k+1}-1-p}{2}$.

**Conclusion:**  The divisors of $2^kp$ can be split into two sets with equal sum if and only if $2^{k+1}-1-p\ge 0$, or equivalently if and only if $p\le 2^{k+1}-1$.

Comment: Nice Solution. Do you have any idea about a more general case when $N = 2^kp^r$ ?

Comment: Have not thought about it. If you ask the question, (and I happen to notice it) I will think about it. With a reasonably high power of $2$ around, there is an awful lot of flexibility. I would expect the splitting can be done whenever it is not obvious that it can't be done.