# Divisors of $q^kp^r$

Tags: number-theory

This is a generalization of my previous problem. Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers. What is the necessary and sufficient condition (in terms of $p,q$ and $k,r$) such that we can partition the divisors of $q^kp^r$ into two sets with equal sum ?

For $p \not = q=2$ it is proved that $r$ must be odd and $q^{k+1} > p$. See [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464382/divisors-of-2kpr)

Comment: can you please supply the link of your previous question in the current one?

Comment: probably making the word previous hyper-linked would make things more obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition.**  Let $p,q$ be primes with $q<p$ and let $n=q^kp^r$ with $k,r\in\mathbb N_0$.
The divisors of $n$ can be partitioned into two sets with equal sum if and only if $q=2$ and $r$ is odd and $p<2^{k+1}$.

*Proof.* In the light of the answer given to  [Divisors of $2^kp^r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464382/divisors-of-2kpr), we need only show that no such partitioning is possible when $q\ne 2$, that is $q\ge 3$, $p\ge 5$.
The sum of divisors of $n$ is
$$\begin{align} (1+q+\ldots+q^k)(1+p+\ldots+p^r)&=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}\frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p-1}\\&<\frac{q^{k+1}}{q-1}\frac{p^{r+1}}{p-1} \\
&=n\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{q-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)\\
&\le n\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\\&<2n.\end{align}$$
Since the biggest divisor $n$ makes up for more than the total sum of divisors, a partitioning into two sets of equal sum is not possible. $_\square$

Comment: I always think "Proposition" is more humble than "Theorem". =)